# How to get store record on itemtap

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I know that in an onItemTap, I can retrieve the corresponding data record by

```
      itemtap : function(dv, index, item, e){
          dv.getStore().getAt(index);
```

But my list is filtered via a collectData-Method, so the indexes do not correspond with the ids in the data store.
Is there any way to get the data record when tapping the list, regardless of the list indexes?

[Update]

The snippet where the listview is embedded looks like this:

```
app.views.MyView = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
    ...
    items: [
        {
            title: _('PanelTitel'),
            xtype: 'panel',
            scroll: 'vertical',
            items: [
                getListView(0)
            ]
        },
        {
            title: _('Second PanelTitel'),
            xtype: 'panel',
            scroll: 'vertical',
            items: [
                getListView(1)
            ]
        }
 ]
```

...

And the getListView-function:

```
function getListView(tab_index) {

    return new Ext.List({
        store: new Ext.data.Store(
            {
                model: "app.models.MyModel",
                sorters: 'created_at'
            }
        ),
        itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
              '<div class="my_row">',
              '  {username}',
              '</div>',
            '</tpl>'
        ),
        onItemDisclosure: true,
        listeners : {
          itemtap : function(dv,index,item,e){
              var rec = dv.getRecord(item);
          }
        },
        collectData: function(records, startIndex) {
           [some sorting...]
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, "this" was an attempt I made. Using "dv", my problem occurs as described.

Comment: Sorry previously I made a wrong comment. dv === this actually.

Comment: Did you share store instances? The `app.stores.mystore`. This doesn't sounds very right. Store shall not shared across different components :)

Comment: Good to know :) I changed the code (see above), but it does not work either.

Comment: Problem? http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/5RRU5/

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and example. I will check it step by step and am sure, I'll find the problem :)

Comment: Ah okay. I hope this is the store problem not the itemtap as it should work well.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code, I always use this:

```
function(dv, index, item, e){
    var rec = dv.getRecord(item);
    //...
}
```

`item`, if I'm not remembered wrongly, is the `Ext.Element` of the clicked `div`, so then you should be fine. `DataView` does provide `getRecord` from `Element`, so you can use it.

If I'm not wrong, I saw this from one of their source file when I happened to face your problem in some months ago.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks - basically, your solution should work fine, but in my case, unfortunately, it does not. I have multiple lists grouped in a panel, and each list is generated by a function "getListView", which looks like this: function getListView(tab_index) {... 
    return new Ext.List({...listeners : {
          itemtap : function(dv,index,item,e){...  Within the itemtap-function, if I call dv.getRecord(item), I get results even from the other listviews, and I don't know why.

Comment: You could list down your full code in your question because it might help us to solve it :)